# Is it possible to scrape Telegram group members Privacy status

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to scrape my own group members, and I want to get which one of them has activated the setting of privacy: Privacy and Security > Privacy > Groups & Channels > Nobody

Is there's anyway of getting this piece of information using Python with Telethon?
Regards

Getting which members has activated the privacy setting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.